# Should a java header be a javadoc or a multi-line comment?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc, multiline

The first would use `/**` like in a javadoc:

```
/**
 * Name: Raymo111
 * Date: April 4th, 2018
 * Description: Stack overflow question about headers
 */
public class whatever {

    //Some code here

}
```

---

And the second would use `/*` like in a multi-line comment

```
/*
 * Name: Raymo111
 * Date: April 4th, 2018
 * Description: Stack overflow question about headers
 */
public class whatever {

    //Some code here

}
```

Comment: In Java, you almost always need the Java doc anyway, so why not just use that?

Comment: If you want to use javadoc use the javadoc tags like @author etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you (or someone) want to generate Javadoc (or keep the possibility for it) from the class, you'll want to use Javadoc comments. If you just want to be different for no reason (or really hate class javadoc), use a regular comment.

Of course if you're making a Javadoc comment, you should put something useful in it. Instead of name, date and description, you'll want to put some information about the class, how to use it etc. Not who made the class and when, that's irrelevant.

Comment: My teacher wants us to use a header with name, date and description. That's why I'm asking whether to use a javadoc or multi-line comment. If I put relevant class stuff in the header, I would obviously use a javdoc.

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter. You can put lines of `//` if you want to. Ask your teacher what kind of comments they want. Don't make an issue out of the types of comments, that's wasting time.